# Puppeteer get multiple iFrames by Class name

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, puppeteer, selector

I have multiple iFrames on my site.
Now I need to access every iFrame and fill out an text input field in it.
So I need something like this:

```
 await page.evaluate(() => {
        let elementHandle = document.getElementsByClassName("card-fields-iframe")[0];
        const frame =  elementHandle.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="number"]');
        frame.value = cardNumberValue;
  let elementHandle2 = document.getElementsByClassName("card-fields-iframe")[1];
        const frame2 =  elementHandle2.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="name"]');
        frame2.value = cardNumberName;
  let elementHandle3 = document.getElementsByClassName("card-fields-iframe")[2];
        const frame3 =  elementHandle3.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="date"]');
        frame3.value = cardNumberDate;
    }
    )
```

This is obviously not possible, because I cant use "document.getElementsByClassName" here.
Is there any way how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` and a `forEach` to loop of the iframes.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card-fields-iframe').forEach((frames, index) => {
    console.log(frames);
  });
});
```

Something like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card-fields-iframe').forEach((frames, index) => {
    let elementHandle = document.getElementsByClassName("card-fields-iframe")[index];

    if (index == 0) {
      let frameOne = elementHandle.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="number"]');
      frameOne.value = cardNumberValue;
    }

    if (index == 1) {
      let frameTwo = elementHandle.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="name"]');
      frameTwo.value = cardNumberName;
    }

    if (index == 2) {
      let frameThree = elementHandle.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('input[id="date"]');
      frameThree.value = cardNumberDate;
    }
  });
});
```